# Overlapping issue in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with this TextInput, whenever i click the TextInput component on my phone, others component overlapping, i try using AreaSafeView, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidView, other library but nothing helps.

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from "react-native"
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import ButtonCommon from "../commons/Button"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Main() {
    const [active, setAtive] = useState(true)
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.banner}>
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.bannerText}>Sự kiện tại NEU</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: '80%' }}>
                    <IconButton icon='menu' iconColor='white' containerColor="#004f9e" size={30} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.top}>
                <Icon name="qrcode" size={180} />
                <Text>Student name </Text>
                <Text>Tổng điểm tích lũy </Text>
                <Text>Sự kiện đã đăng ký </Text>
                <Button title="Điểm danh"></Button>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottom}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: '2%', paddingTop: '2%', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <ButtonCommon
                        active={active}
                        style={styles.buttonLeftStyle}
                        text='Button'
                        onPress={() => {
                            console.log('Button 1');
                            setAtive(!active)
                        }} />
                    <ButtonCommon
                        active={!active}
                        style={styles.buttonRightStyle}
                        text='Button'
                        onPress={() => {
                            console.log('Button 2');
                            setAtive(!active)
                        }} />
                </View>
                <TextInput style={{ width: '100%', borderColor: '#cccccc', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5 }} placeholder="Tên sự kiện" />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: "100%",
    },
    top: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: '95%',
        marginTop: '2%',
        height: '35%',
        borderRadius: 3,
        borderColor: '#cccccc',
        
    },
    bottom: {
        width: '95%',
        height: '60%',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    banner: {
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#004f9e",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 15,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 15,
        height: '10%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    bannerText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    buttonLeftStyle: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 25,
        width: '49%',
        height: '40%'
    },
    buttonRightStyle: {
        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
        width: '49%',
        height: '40%',
    }
})
```

[Before click TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRRz5.jpg)
[When the keyboard show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmUi7.jpg)

I try SafeAreaView, ScrollView but nothing helps.